# What are the advantages of lambda expression over regular function?

Tags: python, lambda

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-lambda-expressions-contain-statements):

> Unlike lambda forms in other languages, where they add functionality, Python lambdas are only a shorthand notation if you’re too lazy to define a function.

Is there an actual advantage using lambda expression over regular functions like a runtime advantage or an aesthetic one? Is there cases where lambda expression are an absolute necessity? I feel like they are just a limited version of functions as they can contain only 1 argument.

I'am not sure to grasp their utility and the concept as a whole beyond the fact that it's an implementation of Alonso Church lambda calculus.

The following compute the product of 2 numbers, and I find the function version clearer.

```py
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))

def times(a,b):
    return a*b

print (times(2,11))
```

Comment: Huh?  Lambdas can have as many parameters as you want, the limitation is that the body can contain only a single expression (implicitly `return`ed), not any statements.  They're purely a convenience for putting the definition right at the point of use, absolutely nothing requires them.

Comment: " Is there cases where lambda expression are an absolute necessity? " No, there isn't.  There *only* purpose is to let you quickly define an anonymous function. Although note, `lambda` functions can take more than one argument.

Comment: The advantage is that the code required to define them is shorter, full stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas can have multiple arguments. A place I find they fit nicely is when I'm creating functional dictionaries. Ex:

```
res = input("Unexpected Input Here")

choices = {
    "x": lambda *data: data[1] / data[0]
    "y": lambda *data: data[1] - data[0],
    "z": lambda data1, data2: data2 * data1
    ...
}

choices[res](100, 20)
```

It's not worth it for me to write these out to multiple functions. This is a fairly trivial example but I use this pattern for HTTP request validation, pandas data manipulation, etc. It's great because you can also iterate over dictionaries and you can create a pipeline of functions (based on specialized logic to skip certain keys, potentially based on the value instance via `isinstance`).